# NLog AsyncTaskTarget does not batch rows after first iteration

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to write a custom async target for NLog that pushes logs to Azure, and ran into an unexpected scenario.  Basically this: when the async task that I am invoking is slow (in this example 1.5s),  after the first batch, all remaining log entries are sent in single batches.

This is reproducable with various values for TaskDelayMilliseconds, and various app delays.  I would expect one "Write" operation every "TaskDelayMilliseconds" except in cases of exceptions / retry.  I suspect this may be a bug in the AsyncTaskTarget, but I'd like a community review before I submit it.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

**This code requires NLog Nuget 4.6.0-rc3.  The new async batched methods to override are not available in the current release.**

```
[Target("AsyncTestTarget")]
public class AsyncTestTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
    protected override void InitializeTarget()
    {
        base.InitializeTarget();

        BatchSize = 10000;
        TaskDelayMilliseconds = 3000;
    }


    protected override Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        InternalLogger.Info($"NLog.Extensions.AsyncTestTarget.WriteAsyncTask()");
        return WriteAsyncTask(new List<LogEventInfo> {logEvent}, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override Task WriteAsyncTask(IList<LogEventInfo> logEvents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        InternalLogger.Info($"NLog.Extensions.AsyncTestTarget.WriteAsyncTask(List) : {logEvents.Count}");
        if (!logEvents.Any())
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        // If this line is commented, the rows are batched as expected.  If this line is left as-is, then after the first batch, records are sent one at a time.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Sample Program Code:

```
class Program
{
    static ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            logger.Info(i.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        }

        logger.Info("Done");

        LogManager.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    }
}
```

NLog Configuration:

```
<nlog internalLogLevel="Debug" internalLogToConsole="true">
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="ConsoleApp1"/>
    </extensions>

    <targets>
      <target type="console" name="console"/>
      <target type="AsyncTestTarget" name="test" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="test" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Screenshot with NO sleep in WriteAsyncTask:
[image: Screenshot #1]

Screenshot with sleep in WriteAsyncTask (the bug):
[image: Screenshot #2]

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please post it here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3185

Answer (score 0):

NLog 4.6.1 has been released that resolves [#3185](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3185) : https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog